# Error al enviar información a Paquete en Oracle desde ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedure

Buen dia, 
estoy tratando de enviar informacion a un paquete en oracle, todo indica estar bien del lado del sistema al ya enviar los datos para actualizar un registro me seguia marcando error, incluso cambie el tipo de dato de decimal a string y ya dentro del store procedure cambiarlo a numeric pero aun asi me seguia marcando el mismo mensaje el ensaje es el siguiente:

> **PLS-00306: WRONG NUMBER OR TYPES OF ARGUMENTS IN CALL TO 
>     'SP_ACTUALIZA_ROL_USUARIO'**

**Este es mi store procedure en el package:**

```
PROCEDURE SP_ACTUALIZA_ROL_USUARIO(V_ACTIVO VARCHAR2,V_ID 
varchar2,V_ID_USUARIO VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
----MERGE ROL USUARIO
MERGE INTO ADQUIS.ROL_USUARIO D
USING (SELECT to_number(V_ID) id_rol,V_ID_USUARIO ID_usuario,V_ACTIVO 
ACTIVO FROM dual) F
ON(D.id_rol=F.id_rol and D.id_usuario=F.ID_usuario )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET D.ACTIVO=F.ACTIVO
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.ID_ROL,D.ID_USUARIO,D.ACTIVO)
VALUES(F.ID_ROL,
F.ID_USUARIO,
F.ACTIVO);
END SP_ACTUALIZA_ROL_USUARIO;
```

**Este es como mando los datos desde el sistema:**

```
private bool ActualizaEstatus_RolAc(List<Rol_Acceso> ra)
    {


        try
        {
            //DateTime fi = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToDateTime(m.FI).ToString("dd/MM/yy"), "dd/MM/yy", null);
            //DateTime ff = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToDateTime(m.FF).ToString("dd/MM/yy"), "dd/MM/yy", null);


            Ora_Conexion_ADQUIS conn = new Ora_Conexion_ADQUIS();
            OracleConnection OraConn = conn.getConn();

            if (OraConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                OraConn.Open();
                // needClose = true;
            }

            #region MMTO VEHICULAR
            foreach (Rol_Acceso r_a in ra)
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = OraConn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "ADQUIS.P_MMTO_VEHICULAR.SP_ACTUALIZA_ROL_USUARIO";

                OracleParameter P_ACTIVO = new OracleParameter();
                P_ACTIVO.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                P_ACTIVO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                P_ACTIVO.Value = r_a.ACTIVO;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(P_ACTIVO);

                OracleParameter P_ID = new OracleParameter();
                P_ID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                P_ID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                P_ID.Value = r_a.ID.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(P_ID);

                OracleParameter P_ID_USUARIO = new OracleParameter();
                P_ID_USUARIO.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                P_ID_USUARIO.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                P_ID_USUARIO.Value = r_a.ID_USUARIO;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(P_ID_USUARIO);

                OracleParameter Parametro = new OracleParameter();
                //PArametro salida 
                Parametro.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
                Parametro.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(Parametro);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                ////cursor
                //OracleRefCursor cursor = (OracleRefCursor)Parametro.Value;
                //OracleDataReader dr = cursor.GetDataReader();

                //while (dr.Read())
                //{
                //    Rol_Acceso b = new Rol_Acceso();

                //    b.ID = Convert.ToUInt16(dr["ID"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["ID"]);
                //    b.NOMBRE_ROL = (dr["NOMBRE_ROL"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["NOMBRE_ROL"].ToString());
                //    b.DESCRIPCION = dr["DESCRIPCION"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["DESCRIPCION"].ToString();
                //    b.ESTATUS_DESC = dr["ESTATUS_DESC"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["ESTATUS_DESC"].ToString();
                //    b.ESTATUS = Convert.ToUInt16(dr["ESTATUS"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["ESTATUS"]);
                //    b.ACTIVO = dr["ACTIVO"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["ACTIVO"].ToString();


                //    l.Add(b);
                //}

                //Parametro.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            OraConn.Close();
            OraConn.Dispose();
            conn = null;
            #endregion


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ViewBag.ContadorRegistros = 0;
            //ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se pudo obtener la fecha de los expedientes. - " + ex.Message);

            log.ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
            //throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema se presenta porque defines un parametro como `cursor` cuando en realidad no usas ninguno

[Calling Oracle stored procedures from Microsoft.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-from-microsoft-net/)

En el codigo del procedure que nos muestras realizas un `MERGE`, pero donde haces el `OPEN ... FOR`

Entiendo que si quietas esta parte

```
OracleParameter Parametro = new OracleParameter();
//PArametro salida 
Parametro.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
Parametro.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

deberia funcionar, porque no tienes ningun retorno de la ejecucion del procedure

Tambien podrias reducir algo el codigo si los parametros los defines usando

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_ACTIVO", OracleType.Varchar2).Value = r_a.ACTIVO;
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_ID", OracleType.Varchar2).Value = r_a.ID.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_ID_USUARIO", OracleType.Varchar2).Value = r_a.ID_USUARIO;
```

Comment: Hola , es cierto , no me di cuenta , como lo copie de uno donde si me devolvia registros olvide comentar el cursor.